# What would be considered a middle class salary in the UK?

Tags: terminology, income

There is a lot of talk about the squeezed middle in the UK, Is class based mainly on income and if so what is considered to be a middle class salary ?

Comment: I'm sure that like anywhere else it depends on location.  "Middle Class" income in London could probably be extremely comfortable further out of the cities.

Comment: "Middle class" isn't solely, or even mainly, defined by income. Are you interested in defining what 'middle class' is? Or are you looking for 'typical salary' figures? If the latter, may pick what you think is a 'middle class' job and ask how much it pays.

Comment: Per DJClayworth the question is deeply naïve in terms of theories of class to the point of being unanswerable.

Comment: You might be interested in [this project](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-21953364) conducted by the BBC to redefine classes in Britain

Comment: A link or reference to the source of "squeezed middle" or some other context would be very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

'Middle class' is an intangible and rather undefined term. 'Middle class' means different things to different people. You can look in the UK census for median household income, but that doesn't mean anything.

The BBC's recent attempt to try and define classes might interest you http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-22000973